# HiddenField has correct Value but displaying the wrong value in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have the following code in a button click method that goes through the rows of a `GridView`. `ServiceFormQuestionTypeIDHF` is a `HiddenField`.

The first time through the `foreach` statement the value of `sfqtIdINT` is 10 and the value of `sfqtIdSTR` is "10" yet the if statement is true. Now the value I am expecting for the `HiddenField.ToInt()` is 1.

I can confirm that the rest of the `foreach` statement and the rest of the if statements display the wrong value in `sfqtIdSTR` and `sfqtIdINT` but the behavior of the if statement is the value I am expecting from that row in the `GridView`. In other words the `HiddenField` has the right value but displays the wrong value.

I can see no reason for this. Can anyone provide a reason for this?

```
 foreach (TableRow tr in FormGV.Rows)
 {
     HiddenField ServiceFormQuestionTypeIDHF = (HiddenField) tr.FindControl("ServiceFormQuestionTypeIDHF");
     int sfqtIdINT = ServiceFormQuestionTypeIDHF.Value.ToInt();
     string sfqtIdSTR = ServiceFormQuestionTypeIDHF.Value;                       
     if ((ServiceFormQuestionTypeIDHF.Value.ToInt() == 1 )||
                        (ServiceFormQuestionTypeIDHF.Value.ToInt() == 2))
     { .......
       .......
     }
```

Comment: Strange issue. Tried doing `if( sfqtIdINT==1 ||  sfqtIdINT== 2)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using GridViewRow instead of TableRow in foreach.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You were spot on. Thanks.